# Searching a file using LINQ

Tags: c#

I have `List<string> NUMBERS = new List<string>()` which contains some words.

I check if the text contains any character from my list, if it does, I write it down and so on until the end. As a result, I have several symbols or phrases, how can I put these in the right order (in the order in which they are indicated in the test)

For example:

The file contains the text: "On July 20 we are going to visit"

Using the `for`, my program received the text: "July 20 are going visit to we On"

How do you match words in the correct order?

```
private static void GetFiles(DriveInfo disk)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(disk.Name);
    foreach(string file in files)
    {
        string reader = File.ReadAllText(file);
        for(int a = 0; a < phrase.Count;a++)
        {
            if(reader.Contains(phrase[a]))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the value oh phrase list? And what are you doing if your if statement results true?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide us with a [mcve].